# Calling Patch.exe from Powershell with p0 argument

Tags: powershell, exe

I'm currently trying to patch some files via PowerShell using Patch.exe

I am able to call the exe using the '&' command, but it doesn't seem to be reading my p0 input. I'm not an expert on PowerShell and any help would be appreciated!

here is what I am calling in PS:

```
$output = & "$scriptPath\patch.exe" -p0 -i $scriptPath\diff.txt
```

My error reads:

```
can't find file to patch at input line 5
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
```

Which I can emulate by leaving out the p0 parameter on my patch file from commandline.

Here are some alternatives I've already tried:

```
#$output = & "$scriptPath\patch.exe" -p0 -i "$scriptPath\diff.txt"

#CMD /c “$scriptPath\patchFile.bat” (where patchFile.bat has %~dp0patch.exe -p0 < %~dp0diff.txt, seems like powershell reads < as 0<, so there is an error there I think)

#GET-CONTENT $scriptPath\diff.txt | &"$scriptPath\patch.exe" "-p0"

#GET-CONTENT $scriptPath\diff.txt | CMD /c “$scriptPath\patch.exe -p0”
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Patch.exe started in the wrong context and I solved this by using Push-Location / Pop-Location

Here is what my code looks like now

```
Push-Location $scriptPath
$output = & "$scriptPath\patch.exe" -p0 -i "$scriptPath\diff.txt"
Pop-Location
```

Keith also mentioned in one of his comments that you can use:

```
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $pwd
```

I have not tested this, but I assume it does the same thing (Keith is a powershell MVP, I am just a student).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$output = & "$scriptPath\patch.exe" -p0 -i "$scriptPath\diff.txt"
```

Comment: @RichardLee Which Patch.exe is this? Does the fact that it indicates it is at input line 5 mean that it is reading your diff.txt file?  If so, how is the filename specified at line 5 in that file?

Comment: I got the patch.exe from gnuwin -- its a windows version of the linux patch command. Yes, I think it is reading my diff.txt correctly. Line 5 just indicates where the diff changes were '@@ -23,7 +23,7 @@' -- however in some other errors it points to the line where it indicates which file to change like "--- CacheLib/config.xml (revision XXXXX)"

Comment: That path looks like a relative path.  If patch.exe happens to be relying on the process's current working directory, you may need to set that manually e.g. `[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $pwd`

Comment: Although the powershell script was starting in the same location as my patch.exe (which was in cachetools), something was misaligned.. I think you are correct, I actually got it working a few minutes ago using Push-Location $scriptPath / Pop-Location!

Comment: Ah in that case, it was just the PowerShell file system provider's current directory which is different from the process's current directory.  The reason for this is you can have multiple runspaces in a process, each CD'd into a different location therefore the notion of a single current directory does not apply very well to a process running the PowerShell engine.